# PHP + No database: Login -> Will this be secure?

Tags: php, database, security, authentication

I want to create a login for admin without database (it's a pretty simple site) here is my code, would this be secure or its easy to use my session? How can I make it better?

index.php

```
<?php
include("auth.php");

if(!checkAuthentication()){
?>
<form method="post" action="?login=1">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<?php
}else{
header("Location: protected_page.php");
exit();
}
```

functions.php

```
    <?php
session_start();

// Check if username and password matches
function authentication($username, $password){
    if($username == md5("admin") && $password == md5("password")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// Check if session data is still valid 
function checkAuthentication(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){
        $result = authentication($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], false);
    }else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $_REQUEST['login'] == 1){
    $username = md5(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
    $password = md5(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));
    if(!authentication($username, $password)){
        echo "Wrong Login.";
    }else{
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        header("Location: http://localhost/login/protected_page.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

protected_page.php

```
<?php
include("auth.php");

if(!checkAuthentication()){
    header("Location: http://localhost/login/index.php");
    exit();
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: ^This, also don't use `md5()` for passwords. It's outdated and was not designed for passwords to begin with. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

Firstly, you're storing the username and passwords in the PHP file itself in plain text. That's not only a bad way to go about things but also a nightmare to maintain. Let's say that your script grows and you need 50 users to use the "secure" area - that's going to be nightmarish to maintain.

Secondly your script doesn't handle attacks well (i.e. brute force). I can throw 5, 50, 500 brute force attacks at it and it won't lock "my" account or IP address. Maybe something to look into.

Passwords should be stored somewhere secure and instead of checking the value of `md5('password') == $_POST['password']` (for example), you should be checking that `md5($_POST['password']) == $hashedpassword` where `$hashedpassword` is a stored hash value somewhere on the site/in a database. That way if someone does get into your site, there's no plain text passwords.

Also I've noticed you're including auth.php in your index.php, but not checking to see if the user is already logged on (this can happen if for example a user closes a browser and can't remember the full URL to the protected area). So what happens if a user logs on twice? What happens if a user hits the login box when they're already logged on? Food for thought.

Lastly, consider (for UX purposes) having index.php check if the user is logged on and if not, divert them to login.php. This means that if they lose connection (browser shut down) and go to `www.yoursite.com`, if they're logged in they can see whatever's there. That's just a personal preference but worth looking into.

**Most imortantly**: Consider using a framework. There's a myriad of reasons why you should and the fact that you're here asking us if it's secure should definitely be reason to tell you that it's not. There's far too many holes in the web as it is, please don't add to them. Unless you're really really really sure of what you're doing - grab a framework.

Comment: Hello, first of all, excellent reply! That was a good read!

Let me do some questions...
1) Where would you recommend storing the password (remember, no database this is a really simple site)

2) What if I create a limit to how many retries before "blocking" (and how to do this without database)

3) I already corrected the index in my code, I didn't even notice at first :P

Thanks

Comment: Oh and I'm not using a framework because I am starting to get the hang of PHP, so since this is a small little personal project im just trying to see if I can weight functions vs class (for login for example), what do you use, classes or functions?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're writing code for a banking institution or just for personal use - start with a good foot (security wise). I understand you're saying it's a lightweight application but a tiny mysql database won't be too difficult to setup & integrate with. Look at `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` for login without a db back end. Have a play and come back with some specific questions and we'll be more than happy to help. We're not not trying to help you but there's a million excellent tutorials online already.

Comment: hello, does that mean that there is no way to create a safe login/logout without database? :(

DO you recommend class or files with functions for a small personal CMS?

Comment: I'm sure there are loads of ways to create a secure standalone php auth script just like there's loads of ways to creat insecure ones too. What do you mean by class or files with functions? Are you asking for libraries/frameworks or are you asking about your architecture? Have a good google, think and come back here with any problems or specific questions. I have to admit that the PHP documentation is awesome so refer to that and back it up with previous questions asked here.